# How to make a button stop listening after being clicked

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i'm new to programming and I recently just learned javascript. Im trying to make this restaurant system where if you click on a table you can set it as clean, full, or dirty and it will change the tables border color. When I click on one table and change its color it works but then when I click on another table and change it's color, it also changes the previous table that I clicked.

```js
// Changes table number
$(".button").click(function(){
    var chosenTable = $(this).attr("id")
    $("h5").html("<h5>Table #: " + chosenTable + "</h5>");
})

// changes border color of tables
$(".button").click(function(){
    var chosenButton = $(this)
    $(".open").click(function(){
        $(chosenButton).css("border", "5px solid #28a745");
    })
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(chosenButton);
    }, 100);
})

$(".button").click(function(){
    var chosenButton = $(this)
    $(".full").click(function(){
        $(chosenButton).css("border", "5px solid rgb(220, 53, 69)");
    })
})
$(".button").click(function(){
    var chosenButton = $(this)
    $(".dirty").click(function(){
        $(chosenButton).css("border", "5px solid rgb(255, 193, 7)");
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Tables</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="sidenav">
        <h5>Tabel #:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block open">Open</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block full">Full</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block dirty">Dirty</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "1">
                <h4 class="tableNumber table1" >Table 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "2">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "3">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 3</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "4">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 4</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "5">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 5</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "6">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 6</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "7">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 7</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "8">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 8</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "9">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 9</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "10">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 10</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "11">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 11</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "12">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 12</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "13">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 13</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "14">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 14</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "15">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 15</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="restaurant.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make a jsfiddle so we can edit it

Comment: @Matt have you checked my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this a different way, attaching and removing listeners IMO is probably overthinking the problem a bit.

A more optimal way would be to track the active table separately, then whenever one of the open/full/dirty buttons are pressed you access whatever table id is selected

```js
var table_number = null;

// Changes table number
$(".button.table").click(function(){
    table_number = $(this).attr("id")
    // Also ensure you're more specific with selectors as you would have problems as soon as you add another h5 tag anywhere
    $(".sidenav h5").html("<h5>Table #: " + table_number + "</h5>");
})

// changes border color of tables
$(".open").click(function(){
    // You can also add additional checks to ensure these buttons aren't clicked before a table is (otherwise you'll get a JS error in console)
    if (table_number == null) {
        alert("Select a table first");
        return false;
    }
    $("#" + table_number).css("border", "5px solid #28a745");
})

$(".full").click(function(){
    $("#" + table_number).css("border", "5px solid rgb(220, 53, 69)");
})

$(".dirty").click(function(){
    $("#" + table_number).css("border", "5px solid rgb(255, 193, 7)");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that when you select a table you assign the current table in `chosenButton` variable and assigns three events one `.open` click event, `.full` click event and `.dirty` click event

This event is getting binded with tht particular button so when once any one of the button `.open`, `.full` or `.dirty` click events are triggered, you need to unbind the rest of the events from that button or else when you click other buttons, the previous events will be triggered.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
// Changes table number
$(".button").click(function(){
    var chosenTable = $(this).attr("id")
    $("h5").html("<h5>Table #: " + chosenTable + "</h5>");
})

// changes border color of tables
$(".button").click(function(){
    var chosenButton = $(this)
    $(".open").click(function(event){
        $(chosenButton).css("background", "green");
        $(".full").unbind('click');
        $(".dirty").unbind('click');
    })
    $(".full").click(function(event){
        $(chosenButton).css("background", "red");
        $(".open").unbind('click');
        $(".dirty").unbind('click');
    })
    $(".dirty").click(function(){
        $(chosenButton).css("background", "yellow");
        $(".full").unbind('click');
        $(".open").unbind('click');
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
    <title>Tables</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="sidenav">
        <h5>Tabel #:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block open">Open</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block full">Full</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block dirty">Dirty</button>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "1">
                <h4 class="tableNumber table1" >Table 1</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "2">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "3">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 3</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "4">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 4</h4>
            </div>
            <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "5">
                <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 5</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "6">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 6</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "7">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 7</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "8">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 8</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "9">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 9</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "10">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 10</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "11">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 11</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "12">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 12</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "13">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 13</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "14">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 14</h4>
        </div>
        <div type="button"  class="button table" id= "15">
            <h4 class="tableNumber">Table 15</h4>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```